# reduce complex common data from angular objects

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have those objects for example [object1,object2,object3]
each object is a row from selected row in the ui-grid in angular.

of course I can update in each select so I can get 1 object per click or all the selected value in each event click. it does not really matter.

object1 contain 2 arrays , I Need the users array from each object 
object1->users array = 0 -name=dani , 1- name=John

object 2->users->0:name:dani, 1:name:Victor,2:name:vika

object3-> users->0:name:cris 1:name:Luke ,2:name:vika

also I have an public array(selectbox) that need to be updated according those objects

$scope.arr= Macel,kiko,dani,vika,Victor,John,cris,Luke

I need a new array that reduce the common users
so the new array will be :Marcel, kiko

new array= [Macel,kiko]

and the new array will populated in the select box
because Marcel and kiko are not appear in the users objects

what is the efficient way to do that in angular ,I already tried 3 nested foreach but it is not efficient way

thx very much

Answer (score 0):

Javascript provides some powerful functions to work with arrays.

You can use filter() to reduce the dataset based on a condition.
You should make use of map() to transform your array object.

Map() and filter() can be chained to achieve what you desire in an efficient way.
It makes the code more readable.

More details here:

[Javascript functional programming](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2015/05/04/functional-programming-in-javascript-map-filter-reduce/)
[Useful Javascript functions](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/)

http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter6.html

Comment: @Patrik hi can you help me with example for my problem